# How do I Change Adobe's Temp Folder?

Tags: windows-10, adobe-photoshop, adobe-creative-cloud

Adobe's temp folder (.../adobeTemp) is taking up a large amount on my C: drive (which is a low storage SSD reserved for Windows 10 and a small amount of programs), and I am wondering how I change the temp folder location. I have already changed the scratch disk location of all Create Cloud applications, and I have also already changed Windows Temp folder location, and nothing has worked.

Comment: Take a look to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JQfPSj7yYJw)

Comment: As stated in my post, I have already changed the Windows Temp folder location.

Answer (score 2):

This folder appears to have been created during software download and installation and can be safely removed.